# How to declare a std::array of variable length globally and get its size if it has std::string as member

Tags: c++, c++11

In C we can create a static global array like below:

```
static struct A a1 [] = { 1,2,3,4};
```

So we can determine the size using below calculation

```
sizeof(a1)/sizeof(a1[0])
```

How can we achieve the same in C++ using std::array if it contains std::string of variable length values strings:

```
struct A
{
std::string b;
int x;
};
```

Comment: You can't have variable length arrays in C++, but your C example doesn't show a variable length array either. Do you need a `std::vector` or just an `std::array` which deduces its length (possible with C++20, I think)?

Comment: Thanks by variable length array I meant that the size of array is not known - as in my example code of C array style declaration

Comment: We know that we can use C style array declaration in C++ but how will I find the size of array if it contains std::string of variable length values strings

Comment: The same way as you do in C, `sizeof(a1)/sizeof(a1[0])`.

Comment: Will the variable length strings literals not matter - if in the first row its value is empty string but second rows has a string of 'x' length?

Comment: The length of strings does not matter at all, `sizeof` any `std::string` is exactly the same. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26b6b35575b2fcea

Comment: If you wanted to know how much total memory a `std::string` takes up then you could do something like `sizeof(str) + str.capacity()`

Comment: Thanks - I got 8 on console when I compile with -std=c++11 - I think that we can use to traverse the array but not when copying it using memcpy

Comment: Please either program C in C, or use modern C++ but don't try do mix C-like things in C++ unless there's a *very* good reason for it. Don't 'traverse' objects using sizeof or whatever hacks. Don't memcpy objects. Have you tried the std::vector approach? (and is a global vector really the best approach)?

Comment: I am in need to create a global declaration of data that will be shared across services - the issue is that the services code is existing while I am adding a new member variable of type std::string

Comment: @tkausl Or better: `std::size(a1)`.

Comment: Your C array doesn't have variable size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your example doesn't use a variable length array (C++ doesn't have the same variable length array feature that C has. C++ has `std::vector`, which is different). The size of your `a1` array is compile-time. The size is determined by initialization: you specified 4 elements to initialize the array, so it will have size of 4.

If you want to have an `std::array`, without specifying the size of it, you can do it with C++17, using the class template argument deduction feature:

```
#include <array>

struct A {
    std::string b;
    int x;
};

std::array a1 = { // template arguments will be deduced
    A{ "a", 1 },
    A{ "abc", 2 }
};

int main() {
    return a1.size(); // will return 2, as a1 has a size of 2
}
```

Doing the same with C++11 is not possible unfortunately.

If you don't have to have an `std::array`, then you can do it just like your example (you can do this, as `sizeof(A)` is a constant, it doesn't matter how big string you have in `b`):

```
struct A {
    std::string b;
    int x;
};

A a1[] = {
    { "a", 1 },
    { "abc", 2 }
};

int main() {
    return sizeof(a1)/sizeof(a1[0]); // returns 2
}
```